# GWT RPC : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am implementing RPC service in my gwt project which use maven and spring integration. When I am trying to run it I am getting following exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

though my code compile perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have gwt-servlet.jar in war/WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

because this class isn't available during runtime in classpath

> com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet